# get the list of a newly(by user) populated listbox

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

**asp .net mvc 4.0, vs10 , razorview**

This is **my listbox :**

```
 <div class="editor-list-field">
      <select name="lbToCreateTable" class="clsToCreateTable" id="idToCreateTable" style="width:150px" size="8" multiple="multiple" >
             @if(Model.ColumnsToCreateTable != null)
             {
                  <option>@Model.ColumnsToCreateTable;</option>
             }
       </select>
 </div>
```

**my Controller :**

```
 public ActionResult About(AboutModel model, string btnTestMail, string btnSendMail, string lbToCreateTable)
    {
        try
        {
            if (btnTestMail != null)
            {
                List<string> lstTableCreateCols = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    if (Request.Form["lbToCreateTable"].ToString().Length > 0)
                    { }

                    HtmlString hs = new HtmlString(model.Content);
                    if (model.TableCreate)
                    {
                        if (hs.ToString().Length > 0 && model.CompanyName != "" && model.MailSubject != "")
                        {
                            CM.CreateMailBody(model.CompanyName, model.MailSubject, hs);
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if (hs.ToString().Length > 0 && model.CompanyName != "" && model.MailSubject != "" && model.ColumnsToCreateTable != null)
                        {
                            List<string> lstColumnsToCreateTable = new List<string>();
                            foreach (SelectListItem str in model.ColumnsToCreateTable)
                            {
                                lstColumnsToCreateTable.Add(str.Selected.ToString());
                            }
                            CM.CreateMailbodyWithTable(model.CompanyName, model.MailSubject, hs, lstColumnsToCreateTable);
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch { }
            }
            else if (btnSendMail != null)
            { 

            }
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            if (btnTestMail == null && btnSendMail == null)
            {

                if (Session["CompanyName"].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    RedirectFromHomeToAbout(model);
                }
            }

        }
        catch { }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**my model:**

```
[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string MailSubject { get; set; }

    public List<string> TableColumn { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public List<string> ColumnsToCreateTable { get; set; }

    public bool TableCreate { get; set; }

    [Display]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Html)] 
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

in my model why i am getting Model.ColumnsToCreateTable = null;

**Bussiness :**

when my view loads, this Listbox will be blank. In this view, there is another Listbox, which is populated correctly. I will populate the ListBoxToCreateTable(which was blank at first). when i submit the form, along with all other data, this list(of newly populated listbox) will sent to my contrller. And i have to do a lot of things with this.

**Question :**

1. How could i solve this issue?
2. is this the right way to do this?
3. any other suggestion?

Comment: please see the Question. I have added Model and conrller.

Comment: Check `model.ColumnsToCreateTable` is not null before adding items to it `model.ColumnsToCreateTable.Add(str)`. If so then add this before adding items `model.ColumnsToCreateTable = new List<string>();`

Comment: but my view is not passing model.ColumnToCreartTable. model is passing null.

Comment: How are you passing the `model` to `view`. post the full `controller` code

Comment: full controller is given. In my Index page i did    return Redirect("Home/About"). when the about controller is called for first time , it has nothing. the method **RedirectFromHomeToAbout(model)**; is then executed. and my aboutView page is then loaded. when i click in btnTestMail, then the model will pass data.

Comment: check of `null` in the controller for `AboutModel model`, if it is `null`, instantiate it

Comment: aboutmodel is not null. other values like companyName, mailSubject , mailContent, EmailAddress are passed correctly. Just the lbCreateToTable listbox's data binding is not correct. the item's which are populated in the Listbox, are not populated in model=>model.ColumnsToCreateTable entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your problem is not so clear, it is hard to say anything specific. You should find out what exactly the problem is. Try to find the answer's of following facts :

1. check your databinding of model.ColumnsToCreateTable.
2. How is your aboutModel is called from index page is not clear, initialize the aboutmodel once before the model is populated.
3. Debug and check from your redirect to where your ColumnsToCreateTable should be populated.

check following link to get more knowledge on listbox databinding.
[bind ListBoxFor with model](http://forums.asp.net/t/1834813.aspx/1?about%20bind%20ListBoxFor%20with%20model%20MVC3)

you should try htmlHelperClass to bind it easily.